# Как сделать так, чтобы последний элемент не переходил на новую строку?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
fun setDataForEventView(): String {
    var textSubtitleEventProgram = ""
    eventPoint.get()?.activities?.forEach {
        val line = String.format("%s - %s - %s\n",
            it.startTime?.toDate()?.getDateStringFormat(TIME_PATTERN),
            it.endTime?.toDate()?.getDateStringFormat(TIME_PATTERN),
            it.description)
        textSubtitleEventProgram += line
    }
    return textSubtitleEventProgram
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun setDataForEventView(): String {
    val textSubtitleEventProgram = eventPoint.get()?.activities?.map {
        String.format("%s - %s - %s",
                it.startTime?.toDate()?.getDateStringFormat(TIME_PATTERN),
                it.endTime?.toDate()?.getDateStringFormat(TIME_PATTERN),
                it.description)
    }.joinToString("\n")

    return textSubtitleEventProgram ?: ""
}
```